# Django template rendering HTML elements in the wrong order

Tags: python, html, django

This is a Django beginner question (or possibly just an HTML problem).

I'm rendering a very simple HTML page with a template (I'll make it look nice later). It has two divs, each containing a header and a table. If I print the rendered content in my view, it looks right, but the HTML delivered to the browser has both headings, **then** both tables.

**Template**

```
<!doctype html>
<html style=\"font-family:Helvetica\>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Choir Database</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/choirdb.css' %}">
  </head>

 <body>
   <!-- MAIN TABLE -->
   <div>
   <h1>{{ title1 }}</h1>
   {% if value_list1 %}
   <table style=\"width:25%;font-family:Helvetica\">
   <tr/>
   {% for valuePair in value_list1 %}
     <tr><td>{{ valuePair.0 }}</td> <td>{{ valuePair.1 }}</td></tr>
   {% endfor %}
   <tr> <td><a href=\"..\">Home</a></td>
   {% else %}
     <p>No values found</p>
   {% endif %}
   </div>

   <!-- SECONDARY TABLE -->
   <div>
   <h2>{{ title2 }}</h2>
   {% if value_list2 %}
   <table style=\"width:25%;font-family:Helvetica\">
   <tr/>
   {% for valuePair in value_list2 %}
     <tr><td>{{ valuePair.0 }}</td> <td>{{ valuePair.1 }}</td></tr>
   {% endfor %}
   <tr> <td><a href=\"..\">Home</a></td>
   {% else %}
     <p>No values found</p>
   {% endif %}
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**View**

```
  context = {
    'title1': 'Liturgy Detail',
    'value_list1': nameValuePairsPiece,
    'title2': 'Laudate Recommendations',
    'value_list2': rec_details,
  }
  output = render(request, 'two_tables.html', context)
  print ("output is " + str(output.content))
  return render(request, 'two_tables.html', context)
```

The print statement shows the HTML I expect (newlines added) - heading 1, table 1, heading 2, table 2:

```
output is b'\n<!doctype html>\n
<html style=\\"font-family:Helvetica\\>\n 
<head>\n   
...
</head>\n\n 
<body>\n   
<!-- MAIN TABLE -->\n   
<div>\n   
<h1>Liturgy Detail</h1>\n   \n   
<table style=\\"width:25%;font-family:Helvetica\\">\n   
<tr/>\n   \n     <tr><td>Liturgy</td> <td>22B</td></tr>\n   \n     
<tr><td>Psalm</td> <td>14:2-5 r.1</td></tr>\n   \n     
<tr><td>Psalm Soft Copy</td> <td>False</td></tr>\n   \n     
<tr><td>Gospel</td> <td>Mark 7:1-8, 14-15, 21-23</td></tr>\n   \n     
<tr><td>Colour</td> <td>Green</td></tr>\n   \n     <tr><td>Notes</td> <td></td></tr>\n   \n     
<tr><td>Theme</td> <td>Word of God, justice, peace</td></tr>\n   \n   
<tr> <td><a href=\\"..\\">Home</a></td>\n   \n   </div>\n   \n   
<!-- SECONDARY TABLE -->\n   <div>\n   <h2>Laudate Recommendations</h2>\n   \n   <table style=\\"width:25%;font-family:Helvetica\\">\n   <tr/>\n   \n     
<tr><td>195</td> <td>Give me a new heart O God</td></tr>\n   \n     
<tr><td>220</td> <td>Grant to us O Lord</td></tr>\n   \n     
<tr><td>302</td> <td>Breathe on me breath of God</td></tr>\n   \n   
<tr> <td><a href=\\"..\\">Home</a></td>\n   \n   
</div>\n 
</body>\n</html>'
```

'View Source' in the browser also shows this order. But the Developer Tools Elements view, and the actual rendered page, both have both headings, then both tables:
[image: Rendered HTML]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's def an HTML issue. You want to put the headline & the table in separate divs and stretch them to 100% width. You also want to close your table before beginning a new one.

```
 <div>
     <div style="width:100%">  <h1>{{ title1 }}</h1></div>
       {% if value_list1 %}
      <div style="width:100%">   
<table style="width:25%;font-family:Helvetica">
       <tr/>
       {% for valuePair in value_list1 %}
         <tr><td>{{ valuePair.0 }}</td> <td>{{ valuePair.1 }}</td></tr>
       {% endfor %}
       <tr> <td><a href=\"..\">Home</a></td></tr></table>
       {% else %}
         <p>No values found</p>
    </div>
       {% endif %}
       </div>
```

try that.